# :focus on links is not working on mobile version of my website

Tags: css, mobile, focus, pseudo-class

I have a curtain menu on the mobile version of my website and I wanted its links to change from white to green when clicked. To do so, I used :focus on the  elements on CSS and even tried adding tabindex="1" to the  on the HTML, but what happens is the following: when I test the mobile version on my laptop by using the inspect tool the links actually have the desired focus effect; however, when I test this on an actual mobile phone, nothing happens - the links just keep their original white color.

Could anyone please help, based on the code I'm leaving below? It sounds like something that should be easy to solve but I've tried zillions of solutions suggested on the web and so far nothing worked :( Thanks in advance!

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.overlay a {
  color: white;
}

.overlay a[tabindex]:focus {
  color: green;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a tabindex="1" href="#">Home</a>
    <a tabindex="1" href="#">About</a>
    <a tabindex="1" href="#">Contact</a>
    <a tabindex="1" href="#">CV</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `:focus` is not a link selector. The link selectors are `:visited`, `:hover` and `:active`. Also nesting css doesnt work. you need SASS as example for that.

Comment: Thank you, @tacoshy - I've also tried :active but for some reason seems not to be working either when in production (it does work locally though). Any suggestion?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? If it works locally then it should work correctly. Have you already cleared the browsers cache? Have you made sure that the correct css is loaded on the webspace?

Comment: I've just realized that the pseudo-classes on mobile are working on Mozilla, but not on Chrome or Safari. I've added -webkit- prior to my CSS rules, but it still doesn't work. Any further tips? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `:active` should work in mobile.
`:focus` is used for `input` tags.

Comment: Thank you, @David - I've also tried :active but for some reason seems not to be working either